# Javascript Maths showing wrong number

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to do maths and i been getting values such as 200052 i.e if i add 2000+52, where it should be 2052. What am i doing wrong or missing something?

```
//get value of amount eneterd
 amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
 //apply percentage
 if(rateExcel.checked = true){
    total= parseINT((amount/100) * 5);
    total= total + parseINT(amount);
//still i get the same, like 20052 instead of 252.
 };
```

Edit: The input is integer, not a string! I see many people trying to be ninja about telling to use parseINT(), but i tried and it didn't work.

Comment: amount is getting a string value, so if a string is appended in your logic which makes the whole thing a string, use  parseInt(amount) or Number(amount)

Comment: As an aside, the line `if(rateExcel.checked = true)` is not doing what you think it is. That's checking the result of an assignment operation (single equals sign) and will always be truthy in this case.

Comment: @serg10 so == to check is the radio button is checked?

Comment: @Nofel, no, just `if (rateExcel.checked)` - there's no need for a comparison against `true` when you already have a boolean value.

Comment: @Nofel you should favour '===' in general, but in this case you'd probably be fine with just `if(rateExcel.checked)`.

Comment: If you have that kind of trouble, you'll also probably have floating point precision errors at some point, which [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript) might help to solve, when you'll have it :-)

Comment: @serg10 he wouldn't be merely "just fine", omitting the '===' should be the canonical way of writing this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You fix this by forcing the `amount` variable to become an int since it's probably received as a string.:

```
total = total + parseInt(amount);
```

Comment: Don't use `parseInt` without a radix

Answer (score 0):

Your amount is a string so you need to convert your amount to number using

```
total= total + Number(amount);
```

Comment: beware of `NaN` values if `amount` is not a valid number.

Comment: @Alnitak then total will be a NaN , correcting the end user is not what asked

Answer (score 0):

```
//get value of amount eneterd
 amount = document.getElementById("amount").value;
 //apply percentage
 if(rateExcel.checked == true){
    total= (parseInt(amount,10)/100) * 5;
    total= total + parseInt(amount,10);
 };
```

Comment: Don't use `parseInt` without a radix

Comment: @Quentin what is radix?

Comment: @Nofel — The number base. If you don't specify it, there are a bunch of rules that JS will apply and you may find your number being treated as octal or hex instead of decimal.

Comment: @nofel > Radix = base

Comment: Yup :)edited my answer accordingly

Comment: @AkshayJ `   total= (parseInt(amount,10)/100) * 5;` why you use 10 next to amount?

Comment: radix is 10 (decimal) :)

Comment: @Nofel that's the radix value that this whole comment thread is about!

Comment: Did the OP actually specify that the number is an integer?  What about error handling (i.e. `isNan()`, or rejecting if an integer is required but one wasn't given?)

Comment: @Alnitak The author didnt specify those details though ;)

Comment: So why have you assumed that the numbers are integers?

Comment: @Nofel is you want your result in decimal system you have to use radix 10 else u can use other numeral system like octal,hexadecimal,etc :)Cheers buddy@Alnitak